# Google GeoCharts Pan/Zoom option?

Tags: javascript, svg, google-visualization

How to Provide Pan/Zoom to Google GeoCharts؟
I know Google GeoCharts does not provide pan/Zoom i have used `svgpan.js` but no luck.
Is there any working samples of geoCharts which has pan/zoom support?

Answer (score 0):

If you consider any other options for rendering vector maps, I can recommend [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com/) which has zoom/pan feature out of the box.